# A commutative but not necessarily associative operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Let $S$ be a set and let $*$ be a binary operation on $S$ satisfying the laws

\begin{align}
        x*(x*y) &= y \quad \text{for all } x, y \text{ in } S,\\
        (y*x)*x &= y \quad \text{for all } x, y \text{ in } S
 \end{align}
Show that $*$ is commutative but not necessarily associative.

I was thinking of letting $x = (a *b)$, $y = b*a$ for each relation and then flipping the values of $x$ and $y$ but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To see it is not necessarily associative, consider $S=\mathbb N$ (including 0) and $x*y=|x-y|$, I leave you with the details of showing this satisfies the properties above, and see it's not associative since $1*(2*3)=1*1=0\neq 2=1*3=(1*2)*3$

Comment: @MorA. But $1 * (1 * 2) = 1 * 1 = 0 \neq 2$.

Comment: I have to say, a _meaningful_ example of a commutative-but-not-associative operation is that in a Jordan algebra $J$, for example the set $J$ of two-by-two real matrices, with operation $x\cdot y=xy+yx$. Perhaps counter-intuitively, $x^{-1}\cdot (x\cdot y)\not=y$ in general... for concrete and meaningful reasons. :)

Comment: Another one is rock-paper-scissors, @paulgarrett. Let $r$ be rock, $p$ be paper, and $s$ be scissors. Let $x\ast y$ be the winner of $x$ versus $y$, and $x$ if $x=y$. Then $(\{ r,p,s\}, \ast)$ is commutative but not associative. For example, $$\begin{align} r\ast(p\ast s)&=r\ast s\\ &=r\\ &\neq s\\ &=p\ast s \\ &=(r\ast p)\ast s.\end{align}$$

Comment: @TheoBendit you're right! I neglected the case where $x<y$! (if $x\geq y$, then $x*y=x-y$, and since $y\geq 0$ we have $0\leq x-y\leq x$, so $x*(x*y)=x*(x-y)=x-(x-y)=y$, but this fails for $x<y$ as your counterexample demonstrates, in fact if $x<y$ we have $x*y=y-x$, so $x*(x*y)=|x-(y-x)|=|2x-y|$, which only equals $y$ if $x=y$ or $x=0$, with the first case impossible since we assumed $x<y$)

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts of the question: a proof of commutativity, and an example of non-associativity. There is an example in the comments that doesn't work, and while there are two previous answers containing arguments, they are, for my tastes, too terse. So, I'm writing an answer.

First, an example. Consider the following operation on $\Bbb{R}$:
$$x * y = -x - y.$$
Then
$$x * (x * y) = x * (- x - y) = - x - (- x - y) = y.$$
Clearly $x * y$ is commutative too, so the other property holds. However, it is not associative, as
$$(1 * 2) * 3 = (-3) * 3 = 0 \neq 4 = 1 * (-5) = 1 * (2 * 3),$$
so associativity doesn't hold in this case.

Next, we have a proof that commutativity does hold in general. Note that our first equalities give us cancellation laws; if we have $a * c = b * c$, then $(a * c) * c = (b * c) * c$, and so $a = b$ (and similarly for the other cancellation law). So, if $x, y \in S$, then
\begin{align*}
x * y = y * x &\iff x * (x * y) = x * (y * x) \\
&\iff y = x * (y * x) \\
&\iff y * (y * x) = (x * (y * x)) * (y * x) \\
&\iff x = x,
\end{align*}
which is true. All the steps work in reverse, by the cancellation laws and the assumed properties.

Answer (score 2):

The example of not-necessary associative you saw already.

It's commutative because $$yx=((xy)((xy)y))x=((xy)x)x=xy.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
x \equiv z \star y\\
(z \star y) \star ((z \star y) \star y) = y\\
(z \star y) \star z = y\\
y \equiv z \star w\\
(z \star (z \star w)) \star z = z \star w\\
w \star z = z \star w\\
$$

Comment: This is difficult to parse. Please consider adding some commentary.